# Tello Video Stream API for Android

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I have looked around and I have been unable to find any support for capturing the video feed coming from a Ryze Tello drone. The [official DJI sample](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample) does not include support for Tello. I have a hunch that the solution involves native calls to `FFMPEG` but I have been unable to pinpoint all the details of the video protocol.

Has anyone looked into this or found useful libraries that support this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code that receives and decodes the h264 video stream provided by Tello SDK team, you can use the "streamon" command: ​https://github.com/dji-sdk/Tello-Python.​​
Please refer to doc/reademe.pdf and the source code under the path of h264 decoder for the specific processing method of the received video stream data.

Before you run the sample code, you should install some dependencies by using the install script.